# Open a directory and process files/folders in background worker query

Tags: c#, filepath

I have the following code, I'm trying to open a directory and process the files in it via the Background worker but I am having issues with it.

The error I have is (The name filePath does not exist in the current context), which I can understand because it's stored in another method? if someone could point out to me what is wrong with my code it would be appreciated. Folderbrowser doesn't work under the Background worker section.

```
private void btnFiles_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //btnFiles.Enabled = false;
        btnSTOP.Enabled = true;
        //Clear text fields
        listBoxResults.Items.Clear();
        listBoxPath.Items.Clear();
        txtItemsFound.Text = String.Empty;
        //Open folder browser for user to select the folder to scan
        DialogResult result = folderBrowserDialog1.ShowDialog();
        if (result == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            //Store selected folder path
            string filePath = folderBrowserDialog1.SelectedPath;
        }
        //Start the async operation here
        backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync();
    }

    private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        //Process the folder
            try
            {
                foreach (string dir in Alphaleonis.Win32.Filesystem.Directory.EnumerateFiles(filePath, "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories, true))
                {
                    //Populate List Box with all files found
                    this.Invoke(new Action(() => listUpdate2(dir)));
                    FileInfo fi = new FileInfo(dir);
                    if (fi.Length == 0)
                    {
                        //Populate List Box with all empty files found
                        this.Invoke(new Action(() => listUpdate1(dir + Environment.NewLine)));
                    }
                }
            }

            //Catch exceptions
            catch (Exception err)
            {
                // This code just writes out the message and continues to recurse. 
                log.Add(err.Message);
                //throw;
            }
            finally
            {
                //add a count of the empty files here
                txtItemsFound.Text = listBoxResults.Items.Count.ToString();

                // Write out all the files that could not be processed.
                foreach (string s in log)
                {
                    this.Invoke(new Action(() => listUpdate1(s)));
                }
                log.Clear();
                MessageBox.Show("Scanning Complete", "Done", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation);
            }
            //If cancel button was pressed while the execution is in progress
            //Change the state from cancellation ---> cancelled
            if (backgroundWorker1.CancellationPending)
            {
                e.Cancel = true;
                //backgroundWorker1.ReportProgress(0);
                return;
            }
            //}
            //Report 100% completion on operation completed
            backgroundWorker1.ReportProgress(100);
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The variable "filePath" is being declared local to the btnFiles_Click method.  In order for it to be used elsewhere, it must be declared global to the code page:

```
public class Form1
{
    private String _filePath = null;

    private void btnFiles_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //get your file and assign _filePath here...
        _filePath = folderBrowserDialog1.SelectedPath;
    }

    private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        //use _filePath here...
    }
}
```

Comment: Note that it is in theory possible for the _filePath variable to remain uninitialized as far as the BackgroundWorker thread knows. If you want to share variables between threads, they should either be protected with a form of synchronization (e.g. lock statement), or should be declared as "volatile". Even on x86 (where data access is volatile semantics always) you don't want to run the risk of some compiler optimization biting you, and with .NET running on other platforms (e.g. ARM) depending on platform-specific behavior's a bad idea.

Answer (score 3):

@DonBoitnott solution is the most general for data flow inside class. Specifically to `BackgroundWorker` there is another one exists

```
private void btnFiles_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ...
    // pass folder name
    backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync(folderBrowserDialog1.SelectedPath);
}

private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    // get passed folder name
    string filePath = (string)e.Argument;
    ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your example too Sinatr

Comment: IMHO, this is actually the better solution, due to the way it avoids cross-thread synchronization issues (see my comment in the other answer). At least when passing value types and immutable reference type objects (like string), cross-thread synchronization issues are completely avoided.